# Why can I not wear multiple hats at the same time?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

You all know that problem. It is Christmas season and Stack Overflow starts the [Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash/info) where you can earn hats. Unfortunately, you can only wear one hat at a time.

Why do we limit ourselves to one hat at a time?

Wouldn't it be great to wear multiple hats at the same time? Especially that some hats are not real hats, but cupcakes. Some stuff could be wonderful combined.

If you also want to live in a world where it is possible to wear multiple hats, vote this up.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159307/how-about-multiple-hats

Comment: Have you ever tried wearing multiple hats? The second one tends to keep falling off for me.

Comment: (Or *[wonderfully](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wonderfully#Adverb)*?)

Comment: Do you work for a startup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the grand scheme of things, nothing has really changed [since 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159307/how-about-multiple-hats).

I've been involved in many of the discussions prepping for Winter Bash each year for the last four years and I can say that it gets floated as an enhancement each year... but it also always gets scoped out due to prioritizing other things.

That's not to say that we'll never do it or it's impossible, more that we have to be judicious about our goals for the event and what the Community is getting out of it and how much dev time we're putting into it and determining how much we're willing to invest. I assume most product teams have similar issues.

Also, while it's not possible to do natively, you can always fudge it by adding a hat, taking a screenshot, uploading the new avatar with the hat already attached... and repeating until you have every hat you could want... if that's what you want to spend your time on. It's not perfect since these hats can't leak out of the avatar the way the active one does but... just be thoughtful about the order you add them in.

Comment: "it also always gets scoped out due to prioritizing other things." **Like what**? How is there an extensive feature list for this sort of easter egg?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Having 40+ hats instead of 20, including large volumes of new hats?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "easter egg"? That is Spring/Fall Bash, not Winter/Summer bash. Also, bonnets, not hats.

Comment: "Having 40+ hats instead of 20, including large volumes of new hats?" Have you considered that maybe people don't want this?